# Do I need a moisture barrier outside my garage wall insulation?

Tags: insulation

I want to insulate my garage and drywall it , The outside walls are bare brick with 2by 4 studded walls on the inside do I have to put a plastic barrier up before I use batted insulation to keep mositure away from the batting

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located, and what is your climate? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are you asking about vapor condensate or rainwater? For the former, see Fresh Codemonger's answer. For the latter, you'd want housewrap _outside_ the wall sheathing.

Answer (score 1):

Placement of vapor barrier depends on location.

In cold climate you place it on the inside before insulation.  So from the inside out, the layers are typically drywall, poly, insulation, sheathing, water resistive barrier (house wrap), rain screen, cladding.